# Вопрос по sql, можно ли это сделать одним SELECT запросом?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

таблица пользователей:

```
users
----------
`id` int(11)
`email` varchar(55)
`login` varchar(55)
```

и таблица заказов

```
orders
--------
`id` int(11)
`user_id` int(11)
`price` int(11)
```

Нужно вывести список logino'в-пользователей, которые сделали более двух заказов.
можно ли это сделать одним SELECT запросом ?

Comment: Запросто. Связать таблицы (JOIN), группировать(GROUP BY), выполнить пост-отбор (HAVING) по посчитанному количеству заказов (COUNT).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. считаем количество заказов:

   ```
   SELECT `user_id` FROM `orders` GROUP BY `user_id` HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
   ```
2. делаем SELECT из users

   ```
   SELECT `users`.`login`
   FROM `users`
   WHERE `users`.`id` IN (
       SELECT `user_id` FROM `orders` GROUP BY `user_id` HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
   );
   ```

Здесь можно увидеть пример исполнения: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2cf1b5217283ea516e434ca65c19a90f&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)

Возможен вариант используя JOIN:

```
SELECT `users`.`login`
FROM `users`
JOIN (
    SELECT `user_id` FROM `orders` GROUP BY `user_id` HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) `more2orders` ON `more2orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`;
```

или

```
SELECT `users`.`login`
FROM `users`
JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
GROUP BY `users`.`login` 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

[PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1fc584993801a0e07d46fc717f3001fb&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Господи, а подзапрос-то тут нафига???